# HashedMap data is lost when accessed from different class - Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm fetching list of doctors from the web and saving it in a hashed map, to use it in **different class**.

Whenever I access the map I **find it empty** (even though I filled it up previously)

```
class DoctorsController {

     static fetchDoctors() async {
//geting a list of doctors from web
 var map = Map<String, dynamic>();
map['action'] = "GET";
 final response = await http.post(root, body: map);


// fill the hashed map with doctors
 for (int i = 0; i < parsed.length; i++) {
      Doctor doctor = Doctor.fromJson(parsed[i]);
      doctors[doctor.id]=doctor;
    }


    static Doctor getDoctorById(Case caseItem){
print(doctors.length);
        return doctors[caseItem.doctorId];
      }
```

Now whenever I call doctors[X]; I get a null instance of doctor
And length is 0.

Comment: Are you calling it from a different isolate? Isolates do not share memory, and that includes the static variables.

Comment: @Ovidiu Sorry i dont know whats isolate, the calling class is from a different package (directory) moved both to same package yet nothing.

Comment: Can you confirm using breakpoints that the part of the code that assigns `Doctor` instances to the list is reached, and you are not getting any exceptions?

Comment: @Ovidiu played around with the getter method and reverted it to as it was before(above) and now it works, guess its a flutter bug.